# ¿Que puede devolver esta función de codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
function add_excursione($params){
    $this->db->insert('excursiones',$params);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

El caso es que la quiero llamar desde el controlador y saber si ha hecho o no una inserción, pero no veo en los manuales que valores puede devolver esta función en caso de que no haga la inserción.

Answer (score 0):

desde el controlador:

```
    $variable = $this->TuModelo->add_excursione($params);
    if($variable){
      echo "Ok";
    }else{
      echo "Error";
    }
```

desde el Modelo:

```
    function add_excursione($params){
      $this->db->insert('excursiones',$params);
      $result = $this->db->insert_id();
      if($result){
       return true;
      }else{
       return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, ahora me queda mucho más claro.

Answer (score 0):

Con tu función:

```
function add_excursione($params){
    $this->db->insert('excursiones',$params);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Si se realiza la inserción, lo que va a devolver es un entero con el ultimo id que se utilizo en tu tabla al momento de hacer la inserción.

En caso de que no se realice la inserción, esto va a depender del driver utilizado para la conexión con la base de datos, por ejemplo con el driver **mysqli** se utiliza la función `mysqli_insert_id` que en su documentación dice:

> La función mysqli_insert_id() devuelve el ID generado por una consulta
>   en una tabla con una columna que tenga el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT. Si
>   la última consulta no fue una sentencia INSERT o UPDATE o si la tabla
>   modificada no tiene una columna con el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT, está
>   función devolverá cero.

Con el driver postgre se podría generar una excepción en caso de que la consulta no funcione.